# how to change the width of a button dynamically

Tags: android

I have a method that creates several buttons

```
public Button[] generaBottoniRisposta(int numeroBottoni, Context context){  
    Button bottoni[]= new Button[numeroBottoni];

    /*genero un tot di bottoni in base a numeroBottoni, è necessario avere il context*/
    for(int i=0; i < bottoni.length;i++){           
            bottoni[i] = new Button(context);
            bottoni[i].setId(i);
            bottoni[i].setText(String.valueOf(i+1));
            LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
            bottoni[i].setLayoutParams(param);          
        }

    return  bottoni;
    }
```

and then another method that add them to a gridlayout.

I want to set the width of those buttons, but i'm not able to do it.

I tried a lot of stuff, `setWidth()`, `setMaxWidth()`, `invalidate()` etc.

Something weird happens. If I try to make the button bigger than its default size it works, if i try  to make the button smaller than its default size it doesn't work!

How should I do? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think setlayoutparams should do what you want. Like in the answer in this thread.
[Set View Width Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343376/set-view-width-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `LayoutParams`, something like..

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_bottone = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
button.setLayoutParams(rel_bottone);
```

And the layout depends on the parent layout that contains the buttons..

Comment: My buttons are inside a gridlayout. I tried to use GridLayout.LayoutParams giving the width of the cells, instead of trying to set the width of the button, and now it seems to work.
But i'm wondering if i can set the width of the buttons in a similar way

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 100;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

one more thing LinearLayout.LayoutParams is used when parent is a LinearLayout and when parent is RelativeLayout use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

My buttons are inside a gridlayout. I tried to use GridLayout.LayoutParams giving the width of the cells, instead of trying to set the width of the button, and now it seems to work.

this is the code I use to add the buttons to the GridLayout

```
Spec row = GridLayout.spec(numeroRiga, 1); 
            Spec colspan = GridLayout.spec(numeroColonna, 1);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams gridLayoutParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row,colspan);
            gridLayoutParam.width=50;
            gridLayoutParam.height=50;

gridLayout.addView(button,gridLayoutParam);
```

But i'm wondering if i can set the width of the buttons in a similar way.