# Set textview width 70% of screen size in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, width, android-linearlayout

I have a simple linear layout with 2 buttons in it.
I set the **layout_width="fill_parent"**

But i want the buttons to occupy 70% of screen size and at the same time
i want them to be centred.
How do i achieve this.?

This is how it looks now.

[image]

i want something like this.

[image]

Thank You.

**EDIT  :** 
The XML code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use LayoutWaight To Set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="button 1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="button 1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This code works but you changed the **orientation** property.
Is it possible without doing that ..??

Comment: No it won't work in case of vertical orientation. If you want layout like image you shown above then u have to use nested layout

Answer (score 4):

- Firstly get screen size in the following way and dynamically set the width of the button as 0.7*screenWidth

> ```
>  DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
>     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
>     int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
>     int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
> ```

- You can set the width dynamically in this way [Set View Width Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343376/set-view-width-programmatically)
- Now set the align parent attribute true in the button layout

Comment: Is it possible to do in XML..??

Comment: As suggested by others try android:layout_weight="0.7"

Comment: But i think, to use **android:layout_weight** we need to change
the **android:orientation** to **horizontal**.
Is it possible to keep orientation vertical and still achieve it.

Comment: YA,AFAIK you can still achieve it

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="button 1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="button 2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this layout file gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `android:weightSum="1"` to the parent layout and `android:layout_weight="0.7"` to the `Buttons` like this:

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:text="BUTTON 1" />
</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:text="BUTTON 1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

or you can assign `Margins` for the root layout like this

```
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
```

But this will not be exactly `70%` of the screen.
Let me know if it works for you.