# Basing a custom View's width off of its height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view

I have a custom View I'm making which has a fixed proportion between width and height. I want the programmer to set the height and I would like the View to set its own width according to a formula based on height.

The View is going to be a child of a RelativeLayout so I can't use the height of the parent element to calculate anything.

**How can I accomplish this?** I don't know how to do it in the `onMeasure` hook because the View's width and height are not available at that time.

By the way, I am making this view solely programmatically, no XML involved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android set height and width of Custom view programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042197/android-set-height-and-width-of-custom-view-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

use [View.setlayoutParams()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))

There's an example using an adView [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343376/set-view-width-programmatically)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14340636)

Comment: @InsaneSkull, fair point. But when the question doesn't have any relevant code, it seems a bit redundant ;)