# How to change layout_weight in my View (programmatically)

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-layout-weight

How can I use Java code to change the `layout_weight` of my `View` object from XML? I've included the last thing I tried below. `vynosy` is my attribute with value that I want to set.

```
View hospVyslLineAppColor = (View) view.findViewById 
                            (R.id.hospodarsky_vysledok_line_appcolor);

hospVyslLineAppcolor.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            Math.abs((float)vynosy)));
```

My XML:

```
<View
     android:id="@+id/hospodarsky_vysledok_line_appcolor"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:layout_weight="69382"
     android:background="#a8a8a8" />
```

Comment: is your view's parent a LinearLayout?

Comment: yes, i have 2 same Views in one Linear ... using like "horizontal graf"

Comment: Hey Tormino, for what purpose do you require to set the weight programatically? To display graph sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for linearlayout

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;  
params.weight = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how the Layout_weights work. These are effective only if you have more than one views. Your code is correct, just you need to add one more view. Both declared in a linear layout. The layout in which you need to have the weights applied.

```
 View hospVyslLineAppColor = (View) view.findViewById (R.id.hospodarsky_vysledok_line_appcolor);

        hospVyslLineAppcolor.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        Math.abs((float)vynosy))); // see to it the value of vynosy is less than 1

 View hospVyslLineAppColor1 = (View) view.findViewById (R.id.hospodarsky_vysledok_line_appcolor);

        hospVyslLineAppColor1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        (1 - Math.abs((float)vynosy)))); // Will complement the weight
```

And re-wite your XML file:

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

          <!-- layout_height is 0dp as height is to be set by weight factor -->
           <View
              android:id="@+id/hospodarsky_vysledok_line_appcolor"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp" 
              android:layout_weight="0.4"
              android:background="#a8a8a8" />

          <!-- layout_height is 0dp as height is to be set by weight factor -->
           <View
              android:id="@+id/hospodarsky_vysledok_line_appcolor1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="0.6"
              android:background="#a8a8a8" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will help you... [Set Width Programatically on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343376/set-view-width-programmatically)

but i think that **is not possible** to change this property programmatically but is only possible to set a new  Layout(View in generally)  within the new property.