# How to dynamically set a view's width

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

Say I have two views,

A Recycler view:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_movie_character"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_movie_horizontal_recycler_view"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

And a text view:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dialog_movie_horizontal_recycler_view"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Add"/>
```

How can I set the recyclerView's width to `match-parent` - `layout_width` of the text view?

Is it possible to do in the xml file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set View Width Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343376/set-view-width-programmatically)

Comment: do yo want recycler view wirth equal to textview/

Comment: It's not. I want to know if I can set the widths in the layout file dynamically.

Comment: I want the Recycler view's width to be the parent width - the width of the text view

Comment: @Cobblestonie Depends on what you have in `recyclerView`. Assuming you have a `CardView` and if `CardView` width it's match_parent then you will reach you goal